# Generating many random numbers within a range with some exceptions in java

Tags: java, list, random

I need to generate lots of random numbers within a range with some exceptions. Right now I'm planning to do it in this way,

```
public class Main
{
    static List<Integer> except = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 25, 28, 29);
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Integer> randomNums = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Random random = new Random();
        
        int z;
        for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
            z = random.nextInt(30);
            while(except.contains(z)) z = random.nextInt(30);

            randomNums.add(z);
        }           
        
        System.out.println(randomNums);
    }
}
```

In my case the size of "except" and "randomNums" will be much higher. So the code will spend much time in the while to avoid numbers that I don't want.

I'm curious to know can I speed up my code? If I can remove the while loop then definitely it will be an O(n). But how can I do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Use a Set instead of a list for `except`. Then the `contains()` method has O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: It's not possible to remove the while loop as far as I can tell!

Comment: I'm thinking, if I can use some sort of mapping from "random number" --> "numbers I need (excluding numbers from except)" then I can remove the while loop. @K. Smith

Comment: is the range of your random numbers changing or constant?

Comment: You could create a list of acceptable numbers and then use a random generator to take numbers from given positions in this list, however I don't know how useful this is as you will have to generate this list at the beginning.

Comment: The range is not fixed but I can handle that, I'm not thinking to generate random numbers by myself, probably using an effective mapping could solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is you make a list of all the numbers you *do* want in your result and each time pick a random member from that list. It requires some initialization, but your loop should run fast after that.

```
    int maxExclusive = 30;
    Integer[] baseArr = new Integer[maxExclusive];
    Arrays.setAll(baseArr, Integer::valueOf);
    List<Integer> base = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(baseArr));
    base.removeAll(except);
    
    List<Integer> randomNums = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Random random = new Random();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Integer z = base.get(random.nextInt(base.size()));
        randomNums.add(z);
    }
    
    System.out.println(randomNums);
```

Example output:

> [1, 10, 27, 2, 24, 22, 7, 8, 0, 27, 19, 27, 15, 14, 21, 22, 13, 24, 2,
> 13]

Comment: @abhimanyue As an aside, just in case you don't want duplicates of the specialize list, you can use `Collections.shuffle` and pull them out of the list in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int exceptMin = 5;
        final int exceptMax = 29;

        Set<Integer> except = new HashSet<>(
                Arrays.asList(5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 25, 28, 29)
        );

        List<Integer> safeValues = getSafeValues(except, exceptMin, exceptMax);

        List<Integer> randomValues = getRandomValues(except, safeValues);
    }

    public static List<Integer> getSafeValues(Set<Integer> except, int exceptMin, int exceptMax) {

        List<Integer> safeValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = exceptMin; i < exceptMax; i++) {

            if(!except.contains(i))
                safeValues.add(i);
        }

        return safeValues;
    }

    public static List<Integer> getRandomValues(Set<Integer> except, List<Integer> safeValues) {

        List<Integer> randomValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 800_0000; i++) {
            int randomNumber = getRandomValue(except, safeValues);
            randomValues.add(randomNumber);
        }

        return randomValues;
    }

    public static int getRandomValue(Set<Integer> except, List<Integer> safeValues) {

        ThreadLocalRandom  random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(0, 30);

        if(except.contains(randomNumber)) {
            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(safeValues.size());
            randomNumber = safeValues.get(randomIndex);
        }

        return randomNumber;
    }
```

So just use another list that stores values that are safe to use and pick one of these if the randomly generated one failed. And as already mentioned by @vanje it uses a HashSet to perform your lookups because it has a constant time complexity for that (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

This approach performs (on my machine) as follows:

```
generated Numbers  time in ms
800_000            300
400_000            156
200_000            87
100_000            38
```

I used the exceptions specified in your answer and generated numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 30(exclusive) so there are a lot of "misses".

However, this approach will cost more memory than generating "fresh" random values and needs some preparation. For example when the exceptions are `{0, 100_0000}` you will generate a lot of "safe" numbers. You could split the `safeNumbers` list into multiple lists to deal with that.
Besides that this method might screw up the distribution of your random numbers (if that is a problem for you).

Edit: As I wrote this answer I did not realize that @Ole V.V. also used this approach. I will delete this answer if requested.

Comment: I suggest that you can leave the answer here. For one thing, some might find your time measurements interesting. Also the use of the `HashSet` may be considered an improvement over my code.